# How to quickly lock screen to landscape?

Tags: cyanogenmod, orientation

For the use with a neoprene bracelet for running, I would like to quickly lock my Milestone 1@Cyanogenmod 7.2.0 to landscape mode. 
All widgets that disable auto orientation seem to cause the phone to switch back to portrait.

I could achieve that by disabling 0°/180°/270° in the settings, but I would like an easier solution with a widget.

Comment: Which widgets have you tried that didn't work? I know [Rotation Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devasque.rotationlocker), for example, has a widget that's designed to lock whatever your current orientation is when pressed.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I overlooked this comment. Yes, Rotation Locker works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Rotation Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devasque.rotationlocker) says that it supports this:

> - Lock your screen's rotation in Landscape, Portrait or Auto. When you launch the app, you're faced with these three options.

For doing this quickly, it does also include a widget to lock whatever your current orientation is:

> - A widget is provided so you can lock into whatever your current orientation is. (Useful for reverse landscape for example).

Comment: Fantastic! An app for everything... :)

Comment: I have attached its launcher icon to Notification Bar using Widgetsoid. Now, I can lock the orientation from within an app. No need to screw Home Launcher.

Comment: Add this tip to answer if you think that it can be useful to someone.